# How to sort div elements according to id from a CSV list using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, sorting, quicksort

I have this info in a variable

```
"sortorder": "obj,exp,qual,edu,int,ref,img
```

I also have corresponding div id's but in shuffled order.

```
<div id = "qual">info</div>
<div id = "exp">info</div>
<div id = "edu">info</div>
<div id = "int">info</div>
<div id = "ref">info</div>
<div id = "img">info</div>
<div id = "obj">info</div>
```

Now i have to sort the div's according to sortorder. 
The first should be obj, second should be exp like this

```
<div id="obj">info<div>
<div id="exp">info<div>
<div id="qual">info<div>
<div id="edu">info<div>
<div id="int">info<div>
<div id="ref">info<div>
<div id="img">info<div>
```

How to do this using jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var sortorder = "obj,exp,qual,edu,int,ref,img".split(',');

$('div').sort(function(a, b){
    return sortorder.indexOf(a.id) > sortorder.indexOf(b.id);
}).appendTo('body');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JYnMd/

Older versions of IE do not support Array object's `indexOf` method, for supporting those pseudo-browsers, you can use jQuery `$.inArray()` utility function:

```
$('div').sort(function(a, b){
  return $.inArray(a.id, sortorder) > $.inArray(b.id, sortorder);
}).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Let's say, I have the HTML in a variable html. Then how to overwrite the html from shuffled div's with sorted div's

Comment: @undefined.  This is great.  Thanks :)