# Sort div elements on page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the code from this question [sort div elements in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394620/sort-div-elements-that-are-stored-in-a-variable-using-jquery). It works perfectly, but rather than storing the div elements in a variable I need to sort them on page.

The  div elements will hold a long menu hence wanting to sort divs on page rather than in a variable.

Comment: here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/decker2/3bjj70h3/5/

Comment: append them to the var html?

Comment: SO read the elements with a jQuery selector, sort, and append them back to the page...

Comment: doesn't the fiddle already do what you ask? the elements are written to the page after sorting.

Comment: Hi @volx757, yes they are written to the page from var html. I need to sort divs already on the page, rather than divs in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

So for your code instead of using an variable use a jQuery selector.

Basic idea on sorting

```js
$("li").sort( function (a,b) { 
  return $(a).text() > $(b).text();
}).appendTo("ul");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</ul>
```

With divs

```js
$(".wrapper div").sort( function (a,b) { 
  return $(a).text() > $(b).text();
}).appendTo(".wrapper");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>C</div>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
</div>
```

and indexOf with ids...

```js
var sortOrder = "Train,Car,Bus";

$(".wrapper div").sort( function (a,b) { 
  return sortOrder.indexOf(a.id) > sortOrder.indexOf(b.id);
}).appendTo(".wrapper");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="Car">C</div>
  <div id="Bus">A</div>
  <div id="Train">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks epascarello. I have used a similar idea with indexOf, but not working on IE. How would this work with divs?

Comment: Should work no differently with divs. Append to the parent

Comment: Thank you. I need to set the sort order via a variable.

Comment: So do it like you did in the other question, instead of using a variable, select the elements....

Comment: I should have used Order by rather than Sort. I want to achieve something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283734/how-to-sort-div-elements-according-to-id-from-a-csv-list-using-jquery

Comment: indexOf doesn't work in IE so moved onto the solution in my question which works perfect except that the divs need to be on page.

Comment: I am not sure how indexOf does not work in IE... But I am not sure why you can not figure out how to take $('<div></div>', {html:html}) and change it to point to the element that holds your divs.